# How to show toast according to the JSONObject response

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask, toast

I am doing an application in which I'm using username and password for log in, if log in is successful I'm getting user_id and all, but when invalid user try to log in, will have to show `toast message` to the user. I'm getting `{"error":"invalid_grant"}` as my JSONresponse and I'm able to get JSONObject in a string.

```
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result);
String aJsonString = jObject.getString("error");
```

Here aJsonString have the value of error in it.

Now, my question is:
How to show an error message when invalid user tries to log in? And, if the user is valid pass the user to `postExecute()` method for further action.

Comment: are you asking how to show toast message?

Comment: I'm asking how to do required action using the JSON string. If I'm getting error message show toast, if not pass it to another activity.

Comment: I know the answer but how you check login successful/failed. Give detail about that.

Comment: @hakiko I check succesful login or failed through JSON response from the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
JSONObject jObject;

    try {
        jObject = new JSONObject(sampledata);
        if (jObject.has("error")) {
String aJsonString = jObject.getString("error");
Toast.makeText(ActivityName.this, aJsonString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
    Toast.makeText(ActivityName.this, "Login Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (JSONException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Thank You for the answer but I need to know how to show different toast if the login is successful. Means no error response I get from the server.

Comment: Two different `toast`, if succesful or on login failed.

Comment: This is not working for me. I'm doing the same thing, but without executing these things, it directly goes to postExecute() method.

Comment: true. because you can display toast in onPostExecute only. doInBackground is only for background processing no UI activity can be done on this.what you can do is pass the result to onPostExecute and at that place write above code

Comment: @ Dinesh Prajapati its very useful answer i vote up..but still one problem is there the message in json is not print in toast.can you help me?

Comment: @Eddie : It depends on your JSON response, paste your code

Comment: @DineshPrajapati i use runonUIbackground() so it works now..but now having problem in success of registration page it shows this error  Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject