# how can i toast message when parsing string = null?

Tags: android

how can i toast message when parsing string = null?
here is my code of json parsing.
basically i need this when there is parsing in no internet service the message pop up with the result there is no net services.

```
JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    hidePDialog();

                    // Parsing json
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {

                            JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            Movie movie = new Movie();
                            movie.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));
                            movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image"));
                            movie.setRating(((Number) obj.get("rating"))
                                    .doubleValue());
                            movie.setYear(obj.getInt("releaseYear"));

                            // Genre is json array
                            JSONArray genreArry = obj.getJSONArray("genre");
                            ArrayList<String> genre = new ArrayList<String>();
                            for (int j = 0; j < genreArry.length(); j++) {
                                genre.add((String) genreArry.get(j));
                            }
                            movie.setGenre(genre);

                            // adding movie to movies array
                            movieList.add(movie);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                    // notifying list adapter about data changes
                    // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    hidePDialog();

                }
            });

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);
}
```

Comment: be more clear with what you want..

Comment: What exactly does not work? Just call Toast.makeText() wherever you register the error...? You need a Context to hand to the makeText() method so you need to make sure you have one around...

Comment: As was mentioned please be more clear. Here is an example using Toast: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15198378/1990536

Comment: i am actually doing parsing by json and i just wanna when my parsing object = null there should be a toast

Comment: Well, after: `JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);` add: `if (obj == null) {Toast.makeText(someContext, "Error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}`. As I said before, the only tricky part - depending on the class where your code is placed - is getting a Context. If you are in Activity just use `this`, in a Fragment use `getActivity()`, etc.

Comment: sorry but this is not working ??

Comment: In what way is it not working? Do you get an error/exception? Is the toast just not shown? Or, most likely, now that I've had a closer look at the Volley API docs: The object is never null when onResponse is called; instead Volley probably goes straight to onError. Try making the Toast there...

Comment: Why don't you show us what is NOT working? A stack trace or exception would be nice. The more specific you are, the better. Is this line throwing an exception when toString() is called? ' Log.d(TAG, response.toString());'

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
 Toast.makeText(Classname, "Message you want", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: how i can implement this toast in json string = null